# Identify String in one Tab, spread String in another tab with the String data

Tags: google-sheets

My request is a little bit difficult to describe so I made an example of what I plan to do but I could not yet:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1sp6LXHFTlB3kAbxvsCfsN5tJTuVlTtp1-p6a01JH93o/edit?usp=sharing

In the tab "Chars", each Char can have one or more Tags (dropdown fed at "Tags"/col Type) in the same line.
In the tab "Tags", each Type can have one or more Skills.

My goal is to have the tab "Results": it should have in one line, the Char, the Type and its skill correspondent to it created automatically. If the Type has more than one skill, it should have another line with all the structure but with the proper Skill. All following new Chars should have the same structure.
Another rule is the Type "All" should be included on every Char.

The sheet is open to be checked, if there is any issue, please ask!

Thank you in advance

Comment: Can you make the sheet editable so that helpers can work in one place?

Comment: @MattKing Done!

Comment: how did you acquire Tag0 in C4:C5?

Comment: see: https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/125018/186471

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an attempt in cell A2 on the MK.Idea tab.

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY(UNIQUE(SPLIT(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(TEXTJOIN("#",TRUE,SUBSTITUTE(TRIM(IF(LEN({Char!A2:A;Char!A2:A;Char!A2:A;Char!A2:A})*LEN(TRANSPOSE(Tags!B2:B))*REGEXMATCH({Char!B2:B;Char!C2:C;Char!D2:D;Char!E2:E},TRANSPOSE(SUBSTITUTE(Tags!B2:B,"All",""))),{Char!A2:A;Char!A2:A;Char!A2:A;Char!A2:A}&CHAR(10)&TRANSPOSE(Tags!A2:A&CHAR(10)&Tags!B2:B),)),CHAR(10),"|")),"#")),"|")),"order by Col1,Col3"))
```

Comment: Tested and looks it work perfectly! I will do some more tests and see if there is any case of exception!

Comment: The way i wrote it there will be a limit on how many characters you can build this for.   Do you know the max you'll ever have?  There is a way to anticipate more, but it's even more complicated so i figured i should start with this.

Comment: I've notice I faced a wall once I added a hundred of them and plus, they add all these extra data so yeah, you are right. I dont know how much will be the max (let us know our limits first), do you have a way to make it receive all data without it having error of too many chars?